# Make Modelica class read-only in Dymola

Tags: dymola

Is there are way to make a user written class read-only in dymola? I want to avoid modifying it by error, when working on models that use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of.  The first is to make the files read only on the file system.  I'm pretty sure Dymola will recognize that fact and prevent modification.  I **think**.

There is also a way to add an annotation that is essentially a checksum or hash or something.  But this is typically done by DS as a way of "signing" libraries.  I don't think there is a way for ordinary users to perform this signing.

Have you check in the documentation?  It might be documented there.  I don't have access to a machine with Dymola on it right now to check.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dymola 2017 FD01 classes can be locked.

- Right-Click a class in the package browser and select *Lock...*
- This will create the annotation

  ```
  __Dymola_LockedEditing="<reason-for-locking>"
  ```

  and the class and nested classes (e.g. classes in a package) are not editable anymore.