# Make a package read only in modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is there a way to make a user created `class/package` to `be read only` in Modelica preferably through annotations? [Make Modelica class read-only in Dymola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282171/make-modelica-class-read-only-in-dymola) gives a `Dymola` option, I am using `OpenModelica` and is required to verify a package across its two different versions, since both these versions are editable I am unknowingly making modifications in the older version. Thanks in advance.

- I tried to search OpenModelica documentation to see if any OM specific annotations are available. But I couldn't spot them. I am pretty much sure that I have missed it in them, probably used a bad keyword.

Comment: You could just make the files your package is made of read-only? Then you can't unknowingly modify them.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being so naive!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OMEdit there are two ways to open a library: either use "File->System Libraries" or "File->Open Modelica/Library File(s)".

The system libraries only shows packages installed at $HOME/.openmodelica/libraries (on Linux; other path in Windows). These are installed by the package manager or installed there manually. When loading libraries through "File->System Libraries", they are always read-only.

If you load the same library by pointing out the package.mo file, it is opened writable.

You can mark a class read-only in the filesystem by not making the file writable (and if you use a hierarchical file structure instead of the whole library in one file, you can restrict editing to only certain parts in this way).

When loading an encrypted library, it is possible to prevent certain operations on the package using annotations, but editing is always restricted.

Comment: You could also export your package as [Read-only Package](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#file-menu).

Comment: Ha, nice, I didn't know that that read-only package export existed! :-)